# Access to a compiled asset with Sprockets 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have an issue migrating from Sprockets 3 to Sprockets 4

In my amp page layout I have

```
- if Rails.application.assets && Rails.application.assets['amp/application']
      style(amp-custom)
        =Rails.application.assets['amp/application'].to_s.html_safe
    - else
      style(amp-custom)
        =File.read("#{Rails.root}/public#{stylesheet_path('amp/application', host: nil)}").gsub(/[\"]/,"'")
```

And of course I have an `amp/application.scss` file with my stylesheet.

With Sprockets 3.0

```
=Rails.application.assets['amp/application'].to_s.html_safe
```

Return to me a compiled version in css, with Sprockets 4 I have only the scss version.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
=Rails.application.assets['amp/application**.css**'].to_s.html_safe
```

I managed to get it works by telling the Sprocket to get the precompiled css file instead of the raw scss file